# fixed gear bicycle chain tension

Tags: fixed-gear

[image]
[image]
[image]

the problem: my chain popped off on my yesterday..and I have no brakes so you can see how that's a problem..
I'm assuming it happened because of the chain being too loose...I'm wondering if it's so loose I should take off a link or what?  for some reason once the chain is on I can't move the wheel back on the dropouts it's like as tight as it will go..
here's a video

Comment: The problem is not the chain tension, the problem is that you have no brakes.

Comment: I get it not having brakes is looked down upon, but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: I’d say there’s a few things that make this an unsuitable fixed gear bike, the QR holding the rear wheel (possibly installed wrongly, lever looks in the open position) in forward facing dropouts, a lack of foot retention and a lack of front brake on a frameset that can accommodate f+r brakes. Once those issues are resolved I would worry about chain tension

Comment: You probably should not use a QR in this situation.  You need something that can clamp the dropouts more securely.

Comment: Definitely *do not remove a link!*  The chain is already about a link too short.

Comment: Sheldon says you can use a QR https://www.sheldonbrown.com/fixed-conversion.html#hub He does recommend a good quality enclosed-cam skewer

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies and wise words, I realized after I filmed the video that my back wheel wasn't centered causing the chain to look much more taut than it is

Comment: Consider fitting chain tugs to hold the wheel in place.  Consider replacing the chain and cog and even chainwheel if it shows wear.  Consider your life and the lives of those you ride near when you have only one brake.  You've survived this accident, what about next time?

Comment: I gotta ask, does that chain appear white in sections due to overspray from when the frame as rattlecanned?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your chain is already too tight. If low chain tension's not the issue, then you need to look for what else might cause this problem.

Check the wear on the chain itself, as well as on the cog and chainring. Check that your wheel is not able to move in the dropout once the quick release is tightened. A bit of play in the bottom bracket could be the cause. Any slight buckle in the chainring or spider could also lead to a dropped chain once you start putting a lot of load on it.

Answer (score 2):

Chain tension should be set so that there is approximately 1/2 inch movement up and down in the chain halfway between the sprocket and chainring. See [this Park Tool video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88tDcVvS7mU) for how to adjust tension (also deals with chain installation and sizing).

If it gives you trouble even with tension set right, check for chain, sprocket and chainring wear. ALso check the alignment between the procket and chainring.